Semisimplicity of algebras in fusion categories
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a fusion category and $A \in \mathcal{C}$ be an algebra object. We say that $A$ is semisimple if its category of (right) modules $\mathsf{mod}_A(\mathcal{C})$ is a semisimple abelian category.
In the specific case where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, it is well-known that $A$ is semisimple if (and only if) $A$ is semisimple in $\mathsf{mod}_A(\mathcal{C})$; i.e. $\mathsf{mod}_A(\mathcal{C})$ is a semisimple abelian category if (and only if) $A$ as a right module over itself is a semisimple module. This is also true for $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{rep}(G)$, it being a consequence of Reiten--Riedtmann's result in "Skew group algebras in the representation theory of Artin algebras".
I am wondering if the same is known (or even true) for general fusion categories. Namely,

Is it true that $A \in \mathsf{mod}_A(\mathcal{C})$ is semisimple if and only if $\mathsf{mod}_A(\mathcal{C})$ is a semisimple abelian category?

Note that semisimplicity of $\mathcal{C}$ is crucial, as this is false if $\mathcal{C}$ is a non-semisimple finite tensor category -- the trivial algebra $\mathbb{1}$ is (semi)simple in $\mathsf{mod}_\mathbb{1}(\mathcal{C}) = \mathcal{C}$.

P/S: I believe I can deduce the result with the extra assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ has a pivotal structure with $\dim(A)\neq 0$. In this case $A$ is Morita equivalent to a direct sum of separable algebras (removing simples in A as necessary), so indeed $\mod_A$ is semisimple. In the general case I still can’t say much; note that separability is also (a priori) stronger than semisimple.

Edit: I made a small error in stating Etingof—Ostrik’s theorem previously. I’ve made the appropriate changes below.
I believe this result was already proven by Etingof—Ostrik in their paper “On Frobenius functor for symmetric tensor categories in positive characteristic” (perhaps modulo one statement, which I’m sure is considered well-known to experts).
Since I am focusing on fusion categories (i.e. semisimple finite tensor categories), let me rephrase their Theorem 12.1 in this setting:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a fusion category and $A$ be an indecomposable algebra in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathsf{mod}_A$ is an indecomposable, semisimple $\mathcal{C}$-module category if and only if $A$ is simple in ${}_A\mathsf{mod}_A$ (the category of $(A,A)$-bimodules) and there exists a monomorphism $A^* \rightarrow X \otimes A$ of right $A$-modules for some $X \in \mathcal{C}$.

Technically, they’ve stated the final condition for left modules, and I have -harmlessly- rephrased it to right modules to fit my setting a little better.
I now claim that in the fusion category setting, if we further assume the stronger assumption on $A$ that it is simple as a right $A$-module (or left; but not necessarily both), then the requirement “there exists a monomorphism $A^* \rightarrow X \otimes A$ of right $A$-modules for some $X \in \mathcal{C}$” always follow. Indeed, any non-zero morphism $\varepsilon \in \hom_{\mathcal{C}}(A,\mathbb{1})$ induces a non-zero morphism of right $A$-modules $\varphi: A \rightarrow A^*$ via
$$\varphi: A \xrightarrow{1 \otimes \cup} A\otimes A \otimes A^* \xrightarrow{m \otimes 1} A \otimes A^* \xrightarrow{\varepsilon \otimes 1} A^*$$
where $\cup$ denotes the coevaluation of the (left) dual of $A$, and $m$ denotes the multiplication of $A$ (this construction was used for example in Kirilov—Ostrik’s $q$-analog of McKay correspondence). Since $\mathcal{C}$ is semisimple and we have a non-zero unit map $u: \mathbb{1} \rightarrow A$, such a non-zero $\varepsilon$ always exists. Moreover, $A$ is simple in $\mathsf{mod}_A$, so the induced morphism $\varphi$ is injective and therefore an isomorphism (via FPdim arguments). This shows that a monomorphism of $A^* \rightarrow X \otimes A$ exists (choose $X=\mathbb{1}$ and $\varphi^{-1}$).
In fact, their conjecture (Conjecture 12.6) is that this existence of monomorphism requirement is superfluous even in the general setting of finite tensor categories and without the stronger assumption of $A$ being simple over itself as a right module; more precisely, the conjecture is that $\mathsf{mod}_A$ is indecomposable exact if and only if $A$ is indecomposable and $A$ is simple in ${}_A\mathsf{mod}_A$.
Note that the proof above does not (directly) translate to this setting, since we have used the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is semisimple to construct a non-zero $\varepsilon$, which may not exists in finite tensor categories (the algebra given by one of the projective in the Taft algebra is an example), and we have used the stronger assumption that $A$ is simple as a right $A$-module.
